# Relationship between number of comparisons between merge sort and merge-insertion hybrid sort

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

I was playing around with a merge-insertion sort hybrid, which looks roughly like this:

```
def hybrid_sort_comparisons(arr, S):
    """
    Performs hybrid sort on `arr` with threshold `S`
    Returns (arr, number_of_comparisons)
    """
    if (len(arr) <= S):
        return insertion_sort_comparisons(arr, S)
    
    num = len(arr) // 2
    left, left_comparisons = hybrid_sort_comparisons(arr[:num],S)
    right, right_comparisons = hybrid_sort_comparisons(arr[num:],S)
    result, number_of_merge_comparisons = merge_comparisons(left, right)
    return result, left_comparisons + right_comparisons + number_of_merge_comparisons
```

It was merge sort, but basically if the array size smaller than a threshold S (I used 7), we would use insertion sort since it has less overhead on smaller arrays.

I ran some exploratory analysis of the hybrid sort function - varying the size of the array, and recording the average number of comparisons required for both the hybrid sort and the merge sort to completely sort the array.

Here is the number of comparisons between merge sort and insertion sort

[image: Time taken for merge sort, and insertion sort]

This made sense, because the number of comparisons should increase as the size of the array to sort increases.

Now, the interesting thing was when I tried to count the difference in the number of comparisons between merge sort and the hybrid sort. Here was what I found:

[image: hybridSortComparisons - mergeSortComparisons against array size]

I knew that the hybrid sort usually takes more comparisons on average than merge sort (because the hybrid sort part takes roughly $O(nS + n \log \frac{n}{S})$ comparisons, while pure merge sort requires $O(n log n)$, so I was expecting to see an upward trending smooth curve.

However, it seems that somewhere a little bit less straightforward. It seems that the curve bounces up and down, and each successive bounce looks like its twice the size of the previous bounce. My guess is that it has something to do with $n/S$, and the ability of evenly splitting $n$ elements into even lists of size $S$, however I am unable to rigorously prove that to myself.

I would like to know why this pattern emerges.

tl;dr: Used a hybrid merge-insertion sort where when the array is small enough, I would use insertion sort, else I would do normal merge sort.

When I compared the `numberOfComparisonsForHybridSort - numberOfComparisonsForMergeSort`, it forms this nice pattern of dipping down in ~$2^n$ increments, however I want to know whats going on behind this.

Comment: Could you make the image border less dark, and also plot not just the *difference* of comparisons but also the two separate counts?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the number of merge "steps" it takes to start with a run size of 1 or 7, until it reaches the size of an array. For pure merge sort, it's 1->2->4->8-> ... -> >= n. For your hybrid sort, it's 7->14->28->56 ... -> => n, plus the overhead of sorting ceiling(n/7) runs via insertion sort. If array size is equal to or slightly less than a power of 2 times 7, the hybrid sort is probably taking fewer comparisons.

Most libraries use a higher size for the insertion sort, usually 16 to 96. Visual Studio uses 32.